# pptpd on Debian doesn't write any logs

Tags: debian, vpn, logging, rsyslog, pptpd

I'm trying to set up PPTP server with Debian Squeeze.

The problem is nothing is being written in the logs (neither in messages nor in debug nor in daemon.log) though `debug` and `dump` options are set. The only line I get after pptpd restart is:

```
# tail -n 1 /var/log/daemon.log
Dec 21 00:25:09 vpn pptpd[1965]: MGR: Manager process started
```

The daemon starts, the port is listened and available to connect. But no logs... I've tried to find pptpd-dbg but debian has no such package.
Any ideas on what's wrong with my config? pptpd or rsyslog ones. Is there any way to get pptpd debug output on stdout?

```
pptpd version 1.3.4-3 (set up from stable repository)
rsyslog version 4.6.4-2 (set up from stable repository)
```

Configurations:
pptpd.conf

```
# egrep -v '^#.*' /etc/pptpd.conf  | egrep -v '^$'
ppp /usr/sbin/pppd
option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
debug
logwtmp
delegate
```

pptpd-options

```
# egrep -v '^#.*' /etc/ppp/pptpd-options  | egrep -v '^$'
name vpn
domain example.com
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
nomppe-40
nodefaultroute
debug
dump
lock
nobsdcomp 
auth
```

rsyslog.conf

```
# egrep -v '^#.*' /etc/rsyslog.conf  | egrep -v '^$'
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err
news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages
*.emerg                         *
daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.err;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry...
Packet filter misconfiguration.

pptpd begins to write to the log file only when it receives a connection. IMHO it should dump the configuration earlier, at start but that's not the topic of the question.

Comment: I didn't have rsyslogd installed! Doh. http://dabase.com/blog/pptpd_VPN_iPhone/

Answer (score 0):

Is /var/log/debug also empty? Try adding `kdebug 1` to pptpd-options. To see pptpd output, run

```
pptpd -d -f -c /etc/pptpd.conf
```